# React router dom routes are loaded onto React Developer tools but the routes are not working in the browser

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am new to React and currently working on a navigation bar. I have index.js which is my startup file

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter} from 'react-router-dom';
import history from 'history';
import Routes from './routes/index';
import Template from './containers/Template';

ReactDOM.render( 
  (
    <BrowserRouter 
        history={history}
        routes={Routes}
    >
        <Template />
    </BrowserRouter>
  ),document.getElementById('root')
);
```

the routes are imported from the routes/index.js file which comes like this

```
import React from 'react';
import {Route, BrowserRouter, Switch} from 'react-router-dom';
import Template from '../containers/Template';
import Home from '../containers/Home';
import Profile from '../containers/Profile';

const createRoutes = () => {
  return (
      <BrowserRouter>
      <Switch>
        <Route path= '/' component= {Template}/>
        <Route path= '/' component={Home}/>
        <Route path= {'/profile'} component={Profile}/>  
      </Switch>
      </BrowserRouter>
  )
}


const Routes = createRoutes();

export default Routes;
```

My main problem is that when I am using chrome and React Developer tools I can see the routes related to the BrowserRouter object as follows
[Routes in the Browser element inspection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRtue.png)

But I cannot open any of the specified routes always getting "Cannot get /profile", note I am using webpack as a web development bundle.

Comment: A navigation bar would have Link tag's right, why are you putting a router for your navbar.
Routes file would be different and independent of any component.

Comment: I think it has to do with you passing `<BrowserRouter />` to itself. That and I believe you need to specify the history object `import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'`. Furthermore looking at the API `<BrowserRouter />` does not accept a `history` prop.
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/BrowserRouter

Comment: Thank you both guys I just read this article were it stated what @VivekN said https://medium.freecodecamp.com/you-might-not-need-react-router-38673620f3d that I can use the react <Link> Object to manipulate the pages without a router

Comment: @rockchalkwushock yes just noticed that but it never stated any errors upon adding it so I should basically create a class that imports history and extends it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is happening here is your webpack-dev-server is trying to serve you an html page called `/profile` which does not exist as you are using a single page app.

Take a look at this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098076/react-router-cannot-get-except-for-root-url) but it comes down to the fact that this is expected behaviour from the webpack-dev-server as the `/profile` html page does not exist.

In order to get this kind of behaviour to work you need to implement server-side rendering or you could use React-Router's hash location

Comment: Thank you!! Yeah now it looks like a totally normal behavior, but if I added the routes in express.js would it be a one page website anymore?, I have already set historyApiFallback to true in my webpack config file

Comment: What you would need to do is re-route the user back into your single page app's root and let your app do the routing on the client side. Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28553904/client-routing-using-react-router-and-server-side-routing) which should help you out

Comment: Also if this answer helped you I would appreciate it if you accepted this answer!

Comment: Sure Thank you again! I am currently figuring out hot to re-rute my app through the react client side, I''ll check the answer onwards and maybe add some in a comment here

Comment: With the help of this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27928372/react-router-urls-dont-work-when-refreshing-or-writting-manually was able to re-route onto my main page and the problem was solved