# react-router-dom is not working with console error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx, react-router-dom

Here is my entry file

*index.js*

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom'

class Hello extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>Hello!</div>
  }
}

class Goodbye extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return <div>Goodbye!</div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <div>
      <Route path="/hello" component={Hello} />
      <Route path="/goodbye" component={Goodbye} />
    </div>
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('app')
)
```

Here is my dependency file

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "React-Router-Redux",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "webpack-dev-server",
    "build": "webpack -p"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "Manoj Kumar",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "prop-types": "^15.5.10",
    "react": "^15.6.1",
    "react-dom": "^15.6.1",
    "react-router-dom": "^4.1.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.2",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.24.1",
    "webpack": "^3.5.5",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.7.1"
  }
}
```

When I go http://localhost:8081/hello or http://localhost:8081/goodbye, it renders `Cannot GET /hello` or `Cannot GET /goodbye` with this console error

```
GET http://localhost:8081/hello 404 (Not Found)
```

or

```
GET http://localhost:8081/hello 404 (Not Found)
```

I use react-router-dom^4.1.2, react^15.6.1. I could not solve this please help me.

**Thank You**

Comment: What are you using to serve your content? I'm assuming webpack dev server? The `Cannot GET` error message is likely webpack related

Comment: Is it correct? It shows only for webpack-dev-server or something else.

Comment: Is what correct? In order for me to figure out if webpack is the problem, show the configuration you have by posting your `webpack.config.js` file

Comment: _webpack.config.js_

[gist link](https://gist.github.com/immanoj16/cc7065dc4b0197bd5f1ad2e33a417b14)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like a Webpack issue. Try adding the line

```
historyApiFallback: true
```

to the `devServer` block of your `webpack.config.js`. This will redirect the 404s back to `/index.html` where they should be properly routed by `index.js`.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098076/react-router-cannot-get-except-for-root-url)'s a thread discussing an issue similar to yours.