# historyApiFallback, React Router v4, Webpack-Dev-Server, "Cannot get /map"

Tags: webpack, react-router, webpack-dev-server, react-router-v4, react-router-dom

I know I'm not the only one facing this issue but after searching the web for a while and trying out everything it gave me, I gotta ask for my case here.

I'm getting the popular error that I receive a 404 whenever I try to access a route of my app, when not using an app-related way. So for example if I refresh my page when I'm at "/map", it says "Cannot get /map".

This is my current configuration, although I tried several ones with different devServer: {} settings and playing with publicPath etc.:

webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");

module.exports = {
    entry: "./src/index.js",
    output: {
        filename: "bundle.js",
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        publicPath: "dist"
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                loader: "babel-loader"
            }
        ]
    },
    devServer: {
        historyApiFallback: {
            index: "dist/index.html"
        }
    }
};
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { connect } from "react-redux";

import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom";

import Homescreen from "./Homescreen";
import Map from "./Map";

import { withStyles } from "material-ui/styles";
import Reboot from "material-ui/Reboot";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "material-ui/Toolbar";
import Typography from "material-ui/Typography";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import IconButton from "material-ui/IconButton";
import MenuIcon from "material-ui-icons/Menu";

const styles = {
    flex: {
        flex: 1
    },
    menuButton: {
        marginLeft: -3,
        marginRight: 20
    }
};

class App extends Component {

    render() {

        const { classes } = this.props;

        return (
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div>
                    <Reboot />
                    <AppBar position="sticky">
                        <Toolbar>
                            <IconButton className={classes.menuButton} color="inherit" aria-label="Menu">
                                <MenuIcon />
                            </IconButton>
                            <Typography variant="title" color="inherit" className={classes.flex}>
                                WeltRaum 31
                            </Typography>
                            <Button color="inherit">Login</Button>
                        </Toolbar>
                    </AppBar>
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Homescreen} />
                    <Route path="/map" component={Map} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        );

    }

};

export default withStyles(styles)(App);
```

Comment: Did you try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/39968984/9034168 ? Maybe it can help

Comment: Yes, I already tried just setting "historyApiFallback" to true, too. Didn't work either :(

Answer (score 10):

@SVARTBERG The following link explains the rationale behind using the webpack configuration setting --> devServer: {historyApiFallback: true }

https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-cannot-get-url-refresh/

You have to add "publicpath" attribute value to '/' in the output object and then add the 'devserver' property as listed below in your webpack configuration file.

```
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'index_bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/'
  },

devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
  },
```

Comment: From review: this does not provide an answer to the question, could you please add this as a comment to the question or the provided compete answer?

Comment: I added more details to my answer. Let me know if that helps.

Comment: The above mentioned link has insightful explanation!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use HtmlWebpackPlugin?
Please first change the public path from `dist` to `/`, then in `devServer` change `historyApiFallback` to `true`. Finally install and require `html-webpack-plugin`, then add this plugin into plugins array on your config

```
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: 'dist/index.html'
    })
  ]
```